# Spring Data Jpa. How to get a list of objects without any relationship

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a entity which has a many relationships to other entities like below:

```
class Customer {

private String email;

// many to many 
private Set<Street> streets

// many to many 
private Set<Address> addresses;

and soo on..
}
```

I would like to find all customers and get back as a list of Customers with set only an emails - without any sets.

It is possible using query extracted from method name? Or only can I get only a list of objects[] and build objects in service?

Comment: Collections are lazy by default, so as long as you don't access them they aren't filled unless of course you made them eager.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `IS EMPTY` JPQL, [as documented here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_empty_comp):

```
@Query("select c from Customer c WHERE c.streets IS EMPTY AND c.addresses IS EMPTY")
List<Customer> findCustomersWithoutRelations();
```

Comment: Customers in database are have releationship already. I don't want to get list of customer which are not have any streets or addreses. I wanted to get only a main object. After thinking ...it was a stiupid question. Query should get a current state of object in the database. If collections are lazy that should be filled when I want to access to them.